# Ethereum contract code visualization

Tags: ethereum, contract

I am using Ethereum with testnet Rinkeby, I created a contract and deployed it. Is there a way to display the source code of that contract? I know that contact are immutable but I want just to have a look on the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to do this and probably will not be for a while, because the code is not published on the blockchain, just the byte code from the compilation.  There are certain block explorers that can help like ether.camp that you can upload solidity code to then it can check against a given address to see if it matches.  There is also a project that is scraping git to find the source code to match byte code.
http://etherscrape.com/about

So no once the code is deployed there is no easy way to see it.